# don't provide only vs don't only provide

Tags: grammar

I am stuck at this problem
"We don't provide only wireless equipment"
 or
"We don't only  provide wireless equipment"
In the above-mentioned sentences, which one is correct? Please help me.

Comment: Though the first variant here shows the more logical placement, the distribution of _focus particles / limiting modifiers_ like 'just', 'only' is notoriously free and complex. The second variant here is probably more commonly used, the first more formal. The second is _marginally_ ambiguous (eg 'We don't only _provide_ wireless equipment ... we _buy back_ your unwanted equipment').

Answer (score -1):

Don't only practice your art, but force your way into its secrets; art deserves that, for it and knowledge can raise man to the Divine. -Ludwig van Beethoven

This is famous quote if you've ever heard about this.

We must use "only" before verb if start with Negativity statement so as per this "don't only provide" is the right statement.

Comment: Thanks, Priyank, It helped me a lot.

Comment: "We don't provide only wireless equipment" means that they provide other things as well. "We don't only provide..." means that they _do_ other things as well, as Edwin implies. Maybe they repair wireless equipment too.